# Session Replication from Websphere to Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, tomcat, websphere

I have a very big monolithic app deployed in websphere, now I am trying to create another app on tomcat on cloud, and need to replicate session from websphere to tomcat.

I have looked on web, session can be easily replicated within websphere or within tomcat, but there's no solution to do the same between two servers, before building any custom solution, just wanted to check if there's any easy way to achieve this.

Websphere version 8.5+, tomcat 8+

Thanks for your help in advance. Session usually has logged in user data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session replication is not standardized, and you'll most likely find various container-specific classes in there - e.g. the user account data that you mention yourself. Thus, session replication is the wrong path to go, it's a dead end and you won't find anything if you look for this solution to the underlying problem.

You might want to look into Single Sign On (which solves your problem of multiple logins) or stateless servers, that don't store any session information at all, so that you can go without any replication.

What exactly works for you depends on your exact underlying problem. Whatever it is, [session replication is not your solution](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Thanks Olaf, will evaluate your suggestion.

Comment: one more doubt, logout happens in main app, how will I be able to monitor this in secondary app. I'll have to keep making calls to SSO server on every request from secondary app.

Comment: Many SSO (Single Sign *On*) solutions also have an offering for SSO (Single Sign *Out*, sic!), where the SSO-server itself invalidates all sessions that were provided with a user's identity. So the answer is: "it depends".